# How to correctly unwrap complex shapes

Tags: uv

I want to unwrap this model to easily paint it but all unwrap types i've chosen produce bad UV, which cannot be used to properly draw textures.

Here's blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj39adxwq3emkda/chefs_band.blend?dl=0

Comment: Many times for any kind of complex mesh the automatic unwrap methods will not work. You are going to have to add in some seams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: 1]

### Overview:

First of all you need to clean up this mesh to have only quad faces, without it this method won't work. This is a good practice and this is a proper topology. That will allow you to use modifiers, better UVs, animations etc.

[image]

1. Next you will need to **Mark Seam** in a place which wouldn't be seen much (back of the hand, or near the body).
2. After that select all and **Unwrap** the mesh.
3. Select one face and straighten it in **UV Image Editor** (<kbd>W</kbd> > **Align Auto** - two vertices at a time).
4. Again select whole mesh an **Unwrap** > **Follow Active Quad**.

Comment: I finally know what "Follow Active Quads" does!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're referring to the selected armband rather than the whole character in the blend. If so then it's fairly simple to unwrap despite being made up of quads and tris.

Simply add a Seam (highlight the edge while in Edit mode and select Mesh/Edges/Mark Seam (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, Mark Seam), then Mesh/UV Unwrap... (or press <kbd>U</kbd>) then Unwrap. This should produce a UV Map similar to the following :

[image: UV unwrap]

To tidy this up you might want to align all the top and bottom vertices in the UV map by selecting all the bottom ones (eg, press <kbd>A</kbd> until none are selected then use Box Select <kbd>B</kbd> and drag the box around the vertices) and scale them to zero height using <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: scale bottom row]

Repeat for the top row of vertices and manually adjust any individual vertices for better spacing if desired.

[image: scale top row]

Comment: Check my answer ;) There is a shortcut.

Comment: @LukeD just spotted your answer just before I completed mine - beat me to it and fixed the topology along the way! :-)

Comment: I have a feeling that we both misunderstood the OP making answers for the band and he probably is asking about whole mesh...

Comment: Perhaps... although the blend file was named 'chefs_band' and that part is selected and filling the view when opening the file... Unwrapping the whole model would be a more complicated undertaking :-D